# How to center jQuery Mobile Popup with scrolled contents?

Tags: jquery

All Popups have the `data-position-to="window"` style.
The body has `style="overflow-x: scroll !important;"`.
And the viewport is set to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

If the user did not scroll all Popups are nicely centred in the browser window. But after a horizontal scroll the Popups are no longer centred and are partial or completely invisible. They can only made visible after scrolling back.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: why don't you position them fixed?

Comment: Is fixed relative to the body or to the window?

Comment: just add `position:fixed;` to your css property

Comment: Tnx, but this makes it only worse. The Popup will be clipped at the right side.

Comment: See the screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xvh7eg3a6nwhq4p/clipped-popup.png?dl=0